# What are my options for using a C++11 library in a C# WPF application?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, windows, c++11

I am writing a cross-platform (OS X and Windows) desktop application in C++11. I intend to use the same C++11 core on both platforms, utilizing native frameworks for the UI (Cocoa and Objective-C on OS X and WPF and C# on Windows) as I believe the best UX experience is a native one.

Currently the application runs as a console app on both platforms. The application performs some CPU-intensive work and provides callbacks for progress reporting and, when complete, instantiates a collection of Items (`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>`) representing the results of the processing.

My goal is for the C++11 library to act as a model for the UI in a manner compatible with the MVC and MVVM patterns.

The UI must:

- Allow the user to choose a file to process (open a file dialog and send the file path to the C++ library)
- Display progress (handle callbacks from the C++ library to update a progress bar)
- Display the results in a WPF form (access the Item class and display information it provides)

I've looked at WinRT and it seems there isn't a lot of information out there for use in desktop applications.  I'm also not fond of the idea of creating the UI itself in C++.  My goal is to get data in and out of the C++ app and use C# to handle the UI as I believe that's a more efficient way of working with WPF.

I'm aware of P/Invoke but my understanding is that it only works with a C interface. Creating such an interface around the C++11 seems cumbersome.

I'm also aware of C++/CLI but I'm not sure if that will meet my needs or if it is compatible with C++11.

I took a look at [CppSharp](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp) but it seems to be a work-in-progress and I doubt I'd know how to work around any issues that may arise.

I have a lot of experience with C++ and a little with C# but I'm not sure if I'm missing better options or which of the above is a sound approach.

Comment: Duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229183/what-are-my-options-for-using-a-c11-library-in-a-c-wpf-application

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend using C++ Interop (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx.aspx). I have used it several times and it is fairly straightforward. In all cases I used it in a WinForms app, not WPF, but I don't think that will be an issue. You will need to create a managed wrapper over your internal CPP implementation. You will need to use C++/CLI for that. And you'll need to marshal your arguments between .NET and C++ native types. There's a bunch of helper functions and smart pointers to help with that. The rest of your code can be native and will compile as usual.